# EclipseLink: How to set SLF4J logger for eclipselink 2.7.0

Tags: java, jpa, logging, osgi, eclipselink

Bundle `org.eclipse.persistence.extension_2.7.0.qualifier.jar` (which I install to osgi framework) contains class `org.eclipse.persistence.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger`. In my persistence file I have

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="org.eclipse.persistence.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger"/>
```

But I get

```
Exception Description: ClassNotFound: [org.eclipse.persistence.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger] specified in [eclipselink.logging.logger] property.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger not found by org.eclipse.persistence.jpa [11]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:231)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28006] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: ClassNotFound: [org.eclipse.persistence.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger] specified in [eclipselink.logging.logger] property.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger not found by org.eclipse.persistence.jpa [11]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.classNotFoundForProperty(EntityManagerSetupException.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.findClassForPropertyInternal(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.findClassForProperty(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1327)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.updateLoggers(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1752)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger not found by org.eclipse.persistence.jpa [11]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1574)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.getClassForName(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.findClass(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1319)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.findClassForPropertyInternal(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1337)
    ... 37 more
```

I've checked bundle `org.eclipse.persistence.extension_2.7.0.qualifier.jar` doesn't export package `org.eclipse.persistence.logging.slf4j` So, could anyone please explain how to make eclipselink to log in slf4j?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you include the "org.eclipse.persistence.extension" jar, and it should work fine.  The maven coordinates I've used are

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
     <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.extension</artifactId>
     <version>2.7.2</version>
     <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `org.eclipse.persistence.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger` is not exported by the providing bundle you will have to adapt it in your code by create a logger class which extends `org.eclipse.persistence.logging.AbstractSessionLog` and override/implement few methods as it is done in original `org.eclipse.persistence.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger`

Basically it is just a copy of the original logger from EclipseLink.

Now in your JPA properties map which is passed to PersistenceProvider while creating an EntityManagerFactory add the EclipseLink logging categories and levels.

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
// Add the necessary logging category and level as per your requirement.
properties.put("eclipselink.logging.level.connection", "FINE");
properties.put("eclipselink.logging.level.jpa", "FINER");
properties.put("eclipselink.logging.level.sql", "FINEST");
// and so on for other categories which can be found in
// org.eclipse.persistence.logging.SessionLog

// Now put your logger class in persistence properties map so that EclipseLink use your logger instance.
properties.put("eclipselink.logging.logger", <your logger>.class.getName());
```

Also make sure to add the following logger with the level of you choice to your logging backend.

For example, with Logback, the declaration will look like this.

```
<logger name="eclipselink.logging" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLING_FILE"/>
</logger>
```

I am adding a GitHub [link](https://github.com/AdeptJ/adeptj-modules/blob/main/data/jpa-eclipselink-extension/src/main/java/com/adeptj/modules/data/jpa/eclipselink/extension/SLF4JLogger.java) from an open source project which has adapted the source code from original `org.eclipse.persistence.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger`

Hope this will help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28363693)

Comment: @NKSM I have updated my answer with enough information. Please see if you still think it is not answering the question. If it is answering then please remove the downvote.

Comment: Any other reviewer care to look into the updated answer I provided, IMO this is now completely fixing the OP's problem.